# Default SIGINT in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sigint

I tried searching the Node.js source code, but I could not find it. By default, where would I find the Node.js code that handles SIGINT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) by default in the following example:

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello Http');
});


server.listen(5001);
```

Comment: Nothing handles SIGINT in your example, except for Node itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node's default SIGINT handler is in node.cc, but it doesn't do much.  It calls signalExit, which does

```
uv_tty_reset_mode();
_exit(1);
```

You can add your own handler in node.js with

```
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    // handle
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That also explains why I could not find it in the .js source code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it yourself. http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events

```
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    //do stuff here.
});
```